# String operations

Tags: string

Can anyone help me with this question:.This is not homework,I am preparing for my technical interview.

Given a series of N strings, find a set of repeating string of size 3
e.g. ababadefb

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind?

Comment: what language do you have in mind? and what do you mean by `repeating string of size 3`

Comment: I wanna do it in java,even I am having problems understanding the question

Comment: i believe this would work in python better

Answer (score 1):

I think we might suffer from not knowing the full problem. I am going to direct you to a blog entry by a friend of mine where he [talks about his interview with Microsoft](http://blogginman.blogspot.com/2010/03/passing-microsoft-interview.html).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to construct a [Suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) from the string, sort it and compute the longest common prefix between the current suffix and the one before it. Now all LCPs of length 3 or more will give you the answer (aba in this case).

```
ababadefb 0
abadefb 3
adefb 1
b 0
babadefb 1
badefb 2
defb 0
efb 0
fb 0
```

---

As an alternate solution you can build a [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) from all suffixes then get all edges that are labeled with strings of length 3 or more.